# How to open a vcproj file from Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eclipse

I know, the question has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181257/any-free-alternative-to-visualstudio) but the answer doesn't meet my requirements.

So is there is any way to import a Visual Studio project with all its parameters in Eclipse CDT ?
If yes, how could I do that ?

*If you want to know more details about my situation, there it is :*

I am joining a rather big collaborative C++ project, with a complex repository and many sub-projects. Each of these sub-projects was initially developed with Visual Studio, and the parameters of the build chain are stored in a vcproj file.

Yet, I strongly resent the use of Visual Studio, am more efficient with Eclipse CDT, and don't have access to a Windows machine, so I would be really happy to not loose weeks in order to understand the whole building process...

Comment: Is there any other build process than Visual Studio? 
I wonder about this, because if it is a Visual Studio Project only, I think you will most likely have much more complicated problems to solve than understanding the build process.
If it is already a cross-plattform project, than maybe some other of the available build processes may easier be converted to Eclipse CDT.

Comment: You could try to "port" the build configuration to CMAKE. CMAKE is able to generate visual studio project files as well as eclipse CDT4 project files (and much more...).

Answer (score 6):

With the risk of being a detracted answer from your question, I believe that the solution is NOT to convert a vcproj to an EClipse CDT project. You should use a better build toolchain (e.g. CMake). Once such a toolchain is in place, you can create a Visual Studio project, an EClipse CDT project, a QtCreator project, a XCode project, ... from the same build configuration files.

That way, when the next IDE for C++ comes along, nobody will be wasting their time converting project files.

Comment: I strongly agree that there is a workflow problem, but I cannot change the way a dozen of people is currently working, in a short amount of time, so I was just asking for a "quick and dirty trick" if possible... 
But I'm totally convinced that, in the long run, another approach should be used...

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking the wrong question. As you've found, the .vcproj describes the build process (in addition to the list of files), and that strongly depends on the MS compiler toolchain being available.

A better alternative (though harder to implement late in the lifetime of a project) is to use free tools such as [Premake](http://industriousone.com/premake) and [JamPlus](http://jamplus.org/) (just to name a few) to decouple the list of files from the build process. This is especially useful for multiplatform projects, as each developer can use their preferred editor and toolchain to contribute to the project.

That being said, I do believe Visual Studio can run under Wine... ;)

Comment: Thank you for the advice ! I will have a look at these tools for later projects.
And, yes, if worse came to worst, I could also consider the Wine alternative :-/