# How to import a Microsoft C++ solution to eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there a migration tool that I can import an existing MSVS solution file into the Eclipse C++ Development Toolkit (CDT)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a vcproj file from Eclipse CDT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449805/how-to-open-a-vcproj-file-from-eclipse-cdt)

Answer (score 8):

I find the easiest way to do this is to simply create a new eclipse project and copy over the settings manually. I use an Eclipse project for browsing as its indexer seems to me to be better than Visual Studio, but I build in Visual Studio.

The settings that are found by right clicking on the project (in project navigator pane on the right by default) and going to "properties". You need to copy the include paths and defines (eg: `/I "C:\includes\"` is an include path, `-D NDEBUG` is a define). You can set up build profiles for each one defined in your solution in eclipse as well.

What would really be great is if Eclipse supported a VC++ toolchain, which it didn't last time I looked into it. (You can do it by manually setting up a toolchain pointing to `cl.exe` etc... yourself)

BTW... you've asked 10 questions and not accepted ANY answers. That's not really fair on the people trying to help you out.

Comment: Which setting do you mean?
can you please give me simple example?

Comment: The settings that are found by right clicking on the project (in project navigator pane on the right by default) and going to "properties". You need to copy the include paths and defines (eg: /I "C:\includes\" is an include path, -D NDEBUG is a define).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such tool. You will need to write your own Makefile and integrate on CDT (or use NMAKE in Visual Studio beforehand so your migration becomes easier).